# Are Factorials just Polynomials

Tags: factorial

I was solving few limit questions based on factorials . They looked scary at first imagining factorials , but you take few terms out and you are done. 
My question is can we find a polynomial such

$${x!}=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+.....a_0$$

We can write
$$x!=(x-(x-1)).(x-(x-2))........(x-(x-(x-1)))$$

It can be a polynomial of maximum of x power.if it does not cancel out.

Is there a way to find coefficient of $x^k$ in this polynomial.

Comment: No: $x!/x^n\to\infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: For factorials x is a integer so can $n=x$

Comment: One can interpret $x!$ as $\Gamma(x+1)$ for real $x$.

Comment: sir now i am interested to find a limit $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x!}{x^x}$$

Comment: Polynomials do not have non-constant exponents, so no, you can't take $n=x$.

Comment: Then see Stirling's formula.

Comment: Thanks I haven't study Study Striling formula , yet it cleared my vision

Comment: Thanks Beautiful Art i think i figure out my mistake. I treated x once like a variable and then a constant

Comment: Let $2\le x\in \Bbb N.$ Let $[x/2]$ be the largest integer not exceeding $x/ 2. $ We have $x/2\ge [x/2]\ge (x-1)/2.$ We have $x!=$ $\prod_{y=1}^{[x/2]}(y)\cdot \prod_{z=1+[x/2]}^x(z)\le$ $ \prod_{y=1}^{[x/2]}(x/2)\cdot \prod_{z=1+[x/2]}^x(x)=$ $x^x/2^{[x/2]}\le$ $ x^x/2^{(x-1)/2}$. Therefore $x!/x^x\to 0$ as $x\to \infty.$

Comment: I think the question was to obtain the coefficients of the falling Pochammer Symbol of x, $x^{\underline{n}}$ as a polynomial in x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreting the question as I think the author had intended, though misunderstanding the meaning of the factorial, we look at the falling Pochammersymbols $x^{\underline{n}}$ Polynomial expansion. The coefficients of this operator, known as Lah numbers. They are given by: $L(n,k)={n-1\choose k-1}\frac{n!}{k!}$. We now have the identity: $x^{\underline{n}}=\sum_{k=1}^n{(-1)^n L(n,k)x^k}$